# Reading text Box from inherited class

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, webforms

i am very new in C# and right now having some problem get read textbox value from the base class.

My base class is

```
public partial class AccidentForm : System.Web.UI.Page
{...}
```

which has multiple text boxes. just to make code readable i created new class and trying to read  `txtAccidentLocAddress.Text` as shown below:

```
public class ComMotorVehiAcc : AccidentForm
{
    public void readpanComMoterVehiAcc()
    {
        txtAccidentLocAddress_panComMoterVehiAcc_str = txtAccidentLocAddress.Text;
    }
}
```

Buts its giving me null. i am missing very basic concept here. Do i need getter setter to access ? or what exactly i am missing ? Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: If I get you correctly, you just need to create an instance of ’AccidentForm’ in your ComMotorVehiAcc class.

Comment: ASP.net webforms do not support inheritance of forms in this way. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have around 60 textbox in one form ... and i am trying to divide them so that my code will be readable.

Comment: just want to do some manipulation in inherited class so that base class is look more readable.

Comment: Are you just trying to split the code for a "single class" across multiple files?  The language supports that.  Look up `partial class`.  It's not the typical usage, and I suspect it won't help with maintainability, but you could try.

Comment: @Flydog57 thanks you .